# Проблемы с LGBMRegressor

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, lightgbm

Пытаюсь для временного ряда (подневного) спрогнозировать объем будущих продаж (раньше использовал fbprophet - получается не очень в силу нерегулярности продаж). По совету обратился к lightgbm.
Проблема следующая:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Usr\Desktop\forecast\new_model0604.py", line 270, in <module>
    X_test = model.predict(future_df)

  File "C:\Users\Usr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\sklearn.py", line 665, in predict
    pred_leaf=pred_leaf, pred_contrib=pred_contrib, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Usr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py", line 2415, in predict
    data_has_header, is_reshape)

  File "C:\Users\Usr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py", line 504, in predict
    data = _data_from_pandas(data, None, None, self.pandas_categorical)[0]

  File "C:\Users\Usr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py", line 344, in _data_from_pandas
    + ', '.join(data.columns[bad_indices]))

ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float or bool.
Did not expect the data types in the following fields: 0, 1, 2
```

Не могу ее устранить.

Привожу фрагмент кода:

```
 model = LGBMRegressor()
 model.fit(firarg, secarg)
 X_test = model.predict(future_df)
 print(X_test)
```

firarg - матрица признаков (n,3), где 3 - год, месяц, день; а secarg - матрица ответов (n,1), т.е. уровень продаж в конкретный день.
future_df - матрицы признаков, аналогичная firarg, но на будущие 100 дней

```
firarg
        0  1   2
0    2018  8  24
1    2018  8  25
2    2018  8  26
3    2018  8  27
4    2018  8  28
..    ... ..  ..
561  2020  3   7
562  2020  3   8
563  2020  3   9
564  2020  3  10
565  2020  3  11

[566 rows x 3 columns]
secarg
     sales
0      2.0
1      3.0
2      0.0
3      0.0
4      0.0
..     ...
561    2.0
562    0.0
563    2.0
564    1.0
565    0.0

[566 rows x 1 columns]
future_df
       0  1   2
0   2020  3  11
1   2020  3  12
2   2020  3  13
3   2020  3  14
4   2020  3  15
..   ... ..  ..
95  2020  6  14
96  2020  6  15
97  2020  6  16
98  2020  6  17
99  2020  6  18
```

Comment: Покажите future_df.info() я по имеющейся ошибке подозреваю, что там у вас тип pandas categorical, а lightgbm такого не ожидает. Можете попробовать дать ему future_df.values, может и прокатит.

Comment: @CrazyElf, print(future_df.info()) вывел просто "None". Попытался с future_df.values - сработало, спасибо огромное!

Comment: Насчёт info загадочно для меня, но главное что всё получилось )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По имеющейся ошибке подозреваю, что там у вас тип `Pandas Categorical`, а `LightGBM` (по крайней мере в имеющейся у вас версии) не умеет работать с таким типом. Можете попробовать дать ему чистый `numpy.array` посредством `future_df.values`, во многих случаях это помогает.